# Filter by variable pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'd like to write a function that filters a `DataFrame` by function inputs. My first attempt here is:

```
def Breakdown(file, key = None, value = None):
    if key is not None:
        if sampreach in ['s', 'S', 'sample', 'Sample']:
            sampreach = sample[sample.key in [value]]
            CountName = 'Total Count'
        elif sampreach in ['r', 'R', 'reachable', 'Reachable']:
            sampreach = reachable[reachable.key in [value]]
            CountName = 'Reachable Count'
    else:
        if sampreach in ['s', 'S', 'sample', 'Sample']:
            sampreach = sample
            CountName = 'Total Count'
        elif sampreach in ['r', 'R', 'reachable', 'Reachable']:
            sampreach = reachable
            CountName = 'Reachable Count'
```

But I got the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'key'
```

The goal is to be able to set `key` equal to the name of a column header and `value` as the name of a value to filter to, or better yet a range of values to filter to.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Could you please provide some sample data and the expected result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing that stands out and could cause the error you're seeing is:

```
sampreach = sample[sample.key in [value]]
```

which might work better as

```
sampreach = sample[sample[key].isin(value)]
```

But as suggested in the comments, there's some info missing (what's `sampreach`, for instance?) as well as sample data and expected output to make a more informed guess at what's going on.